# How to use resolves for routes to lazy load data in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise, angular-routing

Resolves are great, resolve for routes - it's a great way to handle loading of required data, authentication.

```
// Create a function that uses the NameService 
// to return the getName promise.
var getName = function(NameService) {  
        return NameService.getName();
    };

$routeProvider
   .when('/home', {
       templateUrl: '/home.html',
       controller: 'MainController'
   })
   .when('/profile', {
       templateUrl: '/profile.html',
       controller: 'ProfileController',
       /* only navigate when we've resolved these promises */
       resolve: {
           name: getName
       }
   })
```

But in some cases you may want to **lazy load data** when your route changes. There is a tough balance between how much data you want to front-load to a route - mainly due to user experience of the page not switching instantly, and how big of a payload you want to deliver.

looking for better ways to use resolves for routes for such situations.

Comment: `in some cases you may want to lazy load data when your route changes`, they have [events](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#events-1) for that

Comment: You need to hone in what you want to accomplish so that this can be better answered. For instance, if this was display a table of data, you could use a paged resource to load one page worth of records. The rest would be loaded as the user shows interest in viewing them (page button, scroll). There are too many scenarios here to provide a concise answer.